# setCrossProfileCallerIdDisabled not working

Tags: android, android-managed-profile, profile-owner

Did someone used the `setCrossProfileCallerIdDisabled` method of a managed profile? Is it working or not?
When I disable the cross profile caller id, I can still see who is calling me in my unmanaged profile even if the contact is registered only in the managed profile.

Thank you for your review.